# Why I should delete index from the field if there is secondary index field?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I reflect the `_layouts/15/EditIndex.aspx` to see how we can delete the SharePoint List indexes, and I found the following:

```
  protected void DeleteIndex()
        {
            if (this.m_indexId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                if (this.m_secondaryField != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    this.m_list.FieldIndexes.Delete(this.m_indexId);
                }
                else
                {
                    SPField field = this.m_list.Fields[this.m_primaryField];
                    field.Indexed = false;
                    field.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm wondering why they check if there is secondary field and if not they delete the index from the filed. thy can delete the index directly (`FieldIndexes.Delete(this.m_indexId);`), and no need to if statement.

```
 protected void DeleteIndex()
            {
                if (this.m_indexId != Guid.Empty)
                {                       
                        this.m_list.FieldIndexes.Delete(this.m_indexId);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

This probably has to do with compound indexing.  In SharePoint, an index can be based on one column (simple) or two columns (compound).

I think what you are seeing is that SharePoint is checking to see if the index is a compound index or not, and then the "deletion" behavior is different depending on whether it is or isn't.

Comment: but this line of code can delete index for both kinds of index this.m_list.FieldIndexes.Delete(this.m_indexId);

Comment: I'm just speculating based on what you can see in the code.  Obviously `this`, the index object, can have a `m_primaryField` and `m_secondaryField`, and if there is a `m_secondaryField` the behavior is different than if there is not. *Why* it's different I couldn't really say without looking deeper into the code.

Comment: this is the question why it is different, and this is SharePoint code, you an reflect the SP dll and see it